# Restore database without dump but files --> /var/lib/mysql

Tags: database, debian, mariadb, database-restore

I want to know if it is possible to restore my database without dump.

In fact, I had a problem with mysql on my debian 9 server. I uninstall debian and reinstate it. I lost everything but before uninstall debian, I saved ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 files and the database folder with the database name. There files and folder was located in /var/lib/mysql

I already tried to copy and paste the files and the folder on my new debian but it doesn't work...

Is it possible to restore the database with this 3 files and this folder (on the folder, there is .frm and .ibd files) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the entire folder, then you effectively have the entire dataset.  The two things that are elsewhere:

- The MySQL code -- It would be wise to install the same version 5.xx.yy.
- The config file(s) -- /etc/my.cnf (or wherever).  You may have to reconstruct it.  The one tricky setting (if you had changed it) is `innodb_log_file_size`.

I am not sure if there are other *critical* files in the directory other than the 3 files you mentioned.

Give it a try.